# The rotation matrix is non-expansive

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Define for each $\alpha\in \mathbb{R},$
$$A(\alpha)=\begin{bmatrix}\cos\alpha& -\sin\alpha\\ \sin\alpha &\cos\alpha\end{bmatrix}.$$
Then $A$ is non-expansive if $$\|A(\alpha) -A(\beta)\|\leq \|\alpha -\beta\|.$$

So, I'm choosing $\|A\|_{\infty}=\max\limits_{1\leq i\leq 2}\sum^{2}_{j=1}|a_{ij}|.$ Thus, 
\begin{align}  \|A(\alpha) -A(\beta)\|_{\infty}&=\max\{|\cos\alpha-\cos\beta|+|\sin\alpha-\sin\beta|,  |\sin\alpha-\sin\beta|+|\cos\alpha-\cos\beta|   \}\\&= \max\{\left|-2\sin\left(\dfrac{\alpha+\beta}{2} \right) \sin\left(\dfrac{\alpha-\beta}{2} \right)  \right|+\left|2\sin\left(\dfrac{\alpha-\beta}{2} \right) \cos\left(\dfrac{\alpha+\beta}{2} \right)  \right|, \\&\quad\quad\quad\quad \left|2\sin\left(\dfrac{\alpha-\beta}{2} \right) \sin\left(\dfrac{\alpha+\beta}{2} \right)  \right|+\left|-2\sin\left(\dfrac{\alpha+\beta}{2} \right) \cos\left(\dfrac{\alpha-\beta}{2} \right)  \right|  \}  \\&\leq \max\{2\left|\dfrac{\alpha-\beta}{2} \right| +2\left|\dfrac{\alpha-\beta}{2} \right|, 2\left|\dfrac{\alpha-\beta}{2} \right| +2\left|\dfrac{\alpha-\beta}{2} \right|  \} \\&= 2\|\alpha -\beta\|.\end{align}
How I'm I getting $2$ as my constant instead of $1$? Any help in fixing this? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality $(|\cos\, \alpha -\cos\, \beta|+|\sin\, \alpha -\sin\, \beta|) \leq \alpha -\beta $ is false. If thus is true for all $\alpha, \beta$ we can divide by $\alpha -\beta $ and let $\beta \to \alpha$ to see that $|sin\, \alpha| +|cos\, \alpha|\leq 1$. But this is false when $\alpha =\frac {\pi} 4$.

Comment: Right here, I got $(|\cos\, \alpha -\cos\, \beta|+|\sin\, \alpha -\sin\, \beta|)^{2}=2-2\cos(\alpha -\beta)+2|\cos\, \alpha -\cos\, \beta||\sin\, \alpha -\sin\, \beta|.$

Comment: @OmojolaMicheal Look at my answer now. $2|\alpha -\beta|$ the best bound you can get.

Comment: Thanks but how else can I make it non-expansive other than using the identity map?

Comment: If you use the operator norm corresponding to the usual norm on $\mathbb R^{2}$ then we get $\|A\alpha -A\beta\|=|\alpha -\beta|$.

Comment: Sorry, but how?

Comment: The Euclidean norm of $(x\cos \, \alpha -y \sin\, \alpha,x\sin \, \alpha +y \cos\, \alpha)$ is exactly the   Euclidean norm of $(x,y)$.

Comment: I used the Euclidean or Frobenius norm but I got $\|A(\alpha)-A(\beta) \|_2^2=2|\alpha-\beta |^2.$

Comment: The equation you have written is false when $\alpha =0$: we get $A=I$. The norm of this operator for the Euclidean norm (i.e. the domain and range of the linear transformation are **both** given the Euclidean norm)   is $1$, not $2$. You are probably keeping $\|.\|_{\infty}$ on one side.

Comment: Thanks for you help. I used max-norm and this was what I got:   \begin{align}  \|A(\alpha) -A(\beta)\|_{max}&=\max\{|\cos\alpha-\cos\beta|,|\sin\alpha-\sin\beta|\}\\&= \max\{\left|-2\sin\left(\dfrac{\alpha+\beta}{2} \right) \sin\left(\dfrac{\alpha-\beta}{2} \right)  \right|,\left|2\sin\left(\dfrac{\alpha-\beta}{2} \right) \cos\left(\dfrac{\alpha+\beta}{2} \right)  \right| \}  \\&\leq \max\{\left|\alpha-\beta \right|,\left|\alpha-\beta \right| \} \\&= \|\alpha -\beta\|_{max}.\end{align} I guess it's fine, right?

Answer (score 1):

An "abstract" way to prove the same result is to observe that your operator norm $\|A\|_{\infty}$ is nothing but the norm of $A$ as an operator from $\ell_1^n$ to $\ell_{\infty}^n$, where $n=2$. Now you can decompose the operator as follows:
$$\ell_1^n\overset{\text{id}}{\longrightarrow}\ell_2^n\overset{A}{\longrightarrow}\ell_2^n\overset{\text{id}}{\longrightarrow}\ell_{\infty}^n$$
It is easy to check that the identity map from $\ell_1^n$ to $\ell_2^n$ has norm $1$, as well as the identity map from $\ell_2^n$ to $\ell_{\infty}^n$. Since $A$ is an isometry of $\ell_2^n$, we deduce that 
$$\|A\|_{\infty}\leq \|\text{id}\|_{1\to 2}\|A\|_{2\to 2}\|\text{id}\|_{2\to\infty}\leq 1$$.

The advantage of this method is that it proves the same result for any dimension, whenever $A$ is an orthonormal matrix in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

**Edit**: As pointed out by gerw, this does **not** answer the original question.

Comment: I do not see how this answers the question. It was not asked to show $\|A(\alpha)\|_\infty \le 1$, but $\|A(\alpha) - A(\beta)\|_\infty \le |\alpha-\beta|$.

Comment: You are absolutely right.